# How to display labels at vertical axis left (using Charts)?

Tags: ios, charts

How to set vertical axis labels on the left using [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts)?
My coding here:

```
let labels = ["V1", "V2", "V3","V4","V5","V6","V7"]
barChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: labels)
barChartView.xAxis.labelCount = 7
```

But the normal labels are showing at the right.
How can I move the labels to left?

Thanks!

[image: Labels should move to left]

Comment: have you try below answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

```
barChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
```

It works OK.[image: labels at left]

Answer (score 1):

Horizontal Bar Chart

```
barChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
```

Other Graph

```
barChartView.rightAxis.enabled = false 
barChartView.leftAxis.enabled = true
```